# How to add a where clause conditioning another database to OpenQuery linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I am learning about linked server in sql server and I linked the oracle database in sqlserver and ran a query successfully against the oracle linked database as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(DB_ORCL,'select Name, ID from OdataLink.patients')
```

I have a table in sql server as well that I want to use that data in a where clause of OPENQUERY above but do not know how.
Here is the query:

```
Select ID from PatientTable
```

so based on the above sql queries, I want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(DB_ORCL,'select Name, ID from OdataLink.patients')
where "--ID in OPENQUERY above" IN (Select ID from PatientTable)
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(DB_ORCL,'select Name, ID from OdataLink.patients where ID in (--Select ID from PatientTable)')
```

**Update:**

I tested the resolution Stu provided and it almost worked but I cannot call the column field in openquery within the external where clause

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ9d0.png)

Comment: Watch out for OPENQUERYs with WHEREs, since SQL Server cannot "push" the WHERE to the remote server. This means first all remote data will be retrieved and the filtering will be done on your server. This might lead to really bad performance.

Comment: @siggemannen I see, Thank you! do you recommend any other way to perform this action with a better performance? my dataset is not large but I would love to know if there is another way in case I have a larger dataset in the future

Comment: If you for example have a small list of order_group_ids and you know which they are, you might wanna put them inside the openquery condition, so it's like select * FROM openquery(DB_ORCL, 'select Name, ID from OdataLink.patients where order_group_ids  IN (1,2,3,4)') q INNER JOIN patientRecordsSQLServer s ON s.id = q.id. In some cases one can even prepare the where condition by using dynamic SQL to avoid downloading too much data

Comment: wrap it in a CTE and explicitly declare column names`;WITH CTE(col1, col2,..,coln) as (Select openq....) select * from cte join... where cte.colx...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an *exists* correlation

```
select *
from OpenQuery(DB_ORCL,'select Name, ID from OdataLink.patients') q
where exists (
  select * from dbo.PatientTable p
  where p.Id = q.Id
);
```

Comment: Thank you, The issue is that it says q.ID does not exists . I have a join in openquery and the called the ID with alias .

Comment: I added a screenshot in question so you see where the error occured

Comment: Disregard red lines in Management Studio. It cannot resolve column names from openquery. Just try running it and see if you get the error

Comment: Yes have you actually tried running the query? the intellisense won't be able to resolve columns from a linked server.

Comment: You both are right! I Thank you  . I marked it as answer .